# Initialize object variable error

Tags: java

I got an error compiling the following code:

```
class TapeDeck 
{
    boolean canRecord = false;

    void playTape() 
    {
        System.out.println("tape playing");
    }

    void recordTape() 
    {
        System.out.println("tape recording");
    }
}

class TapeDeckTestDrive
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        TapeDeck t; 
        t.canRecord = true;
        t.playTape();

        if(t.canRecord == true) 
        {
            t.recordTape();
        }
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
TapeDeck.java:21: error: variable t might not have been initialized
        t.canRecord = true;
        ^
1 error
```

How shall I initialize the variable `t` in the class?

Comment: You are missing the call to the object's constructor for instantiation. TapeDeck t = new TapeDeck();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `new` keyword to initialize objects.

```
TapeDeck t = new TapeDeck();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can alter the code as:

```
 public class TapeDeck 
        {
           // code
        }

       public class TapeDeckTestDrive
        {
            public static void main(String [] args)
            {
                TapeDeck t = new TapeDeck(); 
                t.canRecord = true;
                t.playTape();

                if(t.canRecord == true) 
                {
                    t.recordTape();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate your TapeDeck object

```
class TapeDeckTestDrive
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        TapeDeck t = new TapeDeck(); 
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create instance of `TapeDeck` and assign it to `t` reference. You can create instance using `new` keyword like

```
TapeDeck t; 
t = new TapeDeck();
```

or in one line

```
TapeDeck t = new TapeDeck();
```

Otherwise `t` stays uninitialized and you can't call any method on uninitialized variable.

---

BTW `if(t.canRecord == true)` is considered as code smell since it can lead to problems like `if(variable=true)` where we assign `true` to variable (`=true`) instead of comparing (`==true`). To avoid such problems simply use

```
if(t.canRecord)
```

or if you feel like having `==` and `true` increases readability so you don't want to remove them use [yoda-condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)

```
if(true == t.canRecord)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize using `new` and the name of your class, in your case `TapeDesck();`.

```
TapeDeck t = new TapeDeck();
```

If you don't do that you won't be able to use any of the methods inside of your class `TapeDesck()`.

If you have a constructor, then you can initialize it with it. For example, if you have this constructor (it's just an example, don't focus on the name of the variables):

```
class TapeDesck
{
   private int number;
   private String prove;

   public TapeDesck(int number, String prove)
   {
       this.number = number;
       this.prove = prove;
   }
}
```

You can initialize it like this:

```
TapeDeck t = new TapeDeck(1,"This is a prove");
```

I expect it will be helpful for you!

Answer (score 0):

You just declared the variable on the `1st line` in your `main()`:

```
TapeDeck t;  // Variable just declared not initialized.
```

#### Solution:

```
TapeDeck t = new TapeDeck();  // Initialize it to use members.
```

You seem to be from `C++` background. This kind of initialization of objects are allowed in `C++` but not in `Java`. You strictly have to use the `new` keyword to initialize an object.